# JavaFX Canvas snapshot save problem due to SwingFXUtils.FromFXImage

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to save the canvas screen shot in the png file, but it gives me following error.

Java version : 10
Javafx version: 11

Sample Code:

```
WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int) canvas.getWidth(), (int) canvas.getHeight());
WritableImage snapshot = canvas.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), writableImage);

File save = new File("Sample.png");
RenderedImage im = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);

try {
    ImageIO.write(im, "png", save);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But following exception is occured.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils (in module javafx.swing) cannot access class sun.awt.image.IntegerComponentRaster (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt.image to module javafx.swing
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(SwingFXUtils.java:284)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: JavaFx version is 11
Java version is 10

Comment: Edit your question and post how you run your application (command line, IDE, Maven or Gradle) and what VM arguments are you using.

Comment: I have similar issue but in my case I got:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = pool-3-thread-1
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:291)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
 ...